# Angular 'duplicates in repeater' error before repeated array is returned

Tags: angularjs

I've just started seeing this error in Angular.js (1.5)

```
Error: Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. Repeater: day in forecast key: string:o
at ngRepeatAction (url...)
```

The strange thing is, that this error shows up in the console before the array of the forecast has been returned.

When the array is returned, it is a unique array

```
[{"print_date":"Tue","long_day":"Tuesday","weather":{"conditions":"Clouds","temps":{"current":19,"max":20,"min":16}}},
{"print_date":"Wed","long_day":"Wednesday","weather":{"conditions":"Clouds","temps":{"current":22,"max":24,"min":15}}},
{"print_date":"Thu","long_day":"Thursday","weather":{"conditions":"Clouds","temps":{"current":22,"max":22,"min":18}}},
{"print_date":"Fri","long_day":"Friday","weather":{"conditions":"Rain","temps":{"current":22,"max":23,"min":18}}},
{"print_date":"Sat","long_day":"Saturday","weather":{"conditions":"Rain","temps":{"current":22,"max":23,"min":15}}}]
```

The forecast array is built via

```
$scope.forecast = (function(){
        var day_list=[];
        for(var d in forecast.data.list){
        var day_weather = formatForecast(forecast.data.list[d],date);
        day_list.push(day_weather);
        }
        return day_list;
    })();
```

Answer (score 0):

Never ever ever do a for in loop when you just want to access the members in the array.  The for in loop should be used when you are going through the properties of an object, NOT the members of the array.  See what happens when you do a normal for loop instead.  Your format forecast is likely creating two identical objects

Comment: I changed it to use a regular for loop, but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I had defined the $scope.forecast as 'loading weather', as a string, and then was replacing it with an array, so angular was converting the string to an array and then noticing that there are duplicate letters.

Stupid mistake on my part, hopefully this helps somebody else.